# Using Owin with ado.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, owin

I am working on a project on ASP.Net with MVC and using ado.net instead of Entity Framework (i mean, all communications with DB done with stored procedure and followed n-tier architecture). Is there any possibility to use OWIN for security and authentication using ado.net?
if not...then suggest any other reference for implementing security and authentication with ADO.Net

Comment: Which version of Asp.Net do you use? And I suppose you mean Asp.Net Identity, when you mention OWIN!?

Comment: why you need identity authentication in Data layer (ado.net).  I hope you are doing something wrong.

Comment: i am using asp.net version 4.6

Comment: so what should i do? Power Star

Comment: Actually you should create your DataAccess Layer with Signle Responsibility Principle. No body will add authentication DL. It should be a plain vennila method. Who ever want to eat they can eat the method.  But these OWIN  kind of authentication and all should be implemented in your presentation layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Owin Authentication In MVC and Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153701/owin-authentication-in-mvc-and-web-api)

Comment: @MuhammadMuneebHafeez Use Asp.Net Identity For authorize and authenticate the request and Use Filter [Authorize]  or create your own to satisfy your need. You need this for Web Api or Controllers ?

Comment: @MalikKashmiri thanks for the answer. I need this for Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement IAuthenticationManager interface, and write your corresponding services which calls the ADO.Net codes in there.
Rick Strahls [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application) explains well enough.

Comment: OP asked authentication for ADO.net. Why you are suggesting add owin authentication in Data Layer.

Comment: I do not think that he means to do so, just instead of using EF he wants to use the plain ado.net codes. correct me if i am wrong